# How can I filter matplotlib basemap boundary data to specific countries or states?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib basemap to draw a map of the continental US. Is there some way to filter the coastline/country boundaries to just the US?  Being Canadian I don't normally like to exclude Canada but would like to in this instance :-)

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
m = Basemap(width=5e6,height=3e6,projection='laea',
        resolution='c',lat_0=39, lon_0=-96)
m.drawcoastlines(color="grey")
m.drawcountries(color="grey")
m.drawstates(color="grey")

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5):

You might want to check out [`Cartopy`](http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/) instead. Basemap is mainly concerned with different map projections of the Earth, while Cartopy has the ability to use arbitrary maps from the [NaturalEarthData](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/) datasets using the [shapereader](http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/tutorials/using_the_shapereader.html). Check out [this example](http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/examples/hurricane_katrina.html) showing Hurricane Katrina's path over the continental US:

[image: katrina]

Comment: Yes, that looks interesting.  I was hoping for something like the `countries.features.filter()` or `topojson.mesh(..., filter)` idiom in [D3js](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/API-Reference) so that I could prune the boundaries before I called `m.drawxxx()`